# show div when option already selected

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, select

Hi guys i using this jquery to show a div when i select a option

```
$("#select1").change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "2" ) {
            $("#hide1").fadeIn("fast"); 
        } else {
            $("#hide1").fadeOut("fast");
        }
    });


});
```

But i have a problem when i load the page get results from database, the option on select return SELECTED and the div only shows if i change the option..

can samebody help what i neeed to do to solve this?

explain again: get the val() from select and show the div without change the option... sorry for my english..

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the change after you bind it.

```
$('#select1').change( function(){
    // your change code
    if ($(this).val() == "2" ) {
        $("#hide1").fadeIn("fast"); 
    } else {
        $("#hide1").fadeOut("fast");
    }

}).change();
```

Answer (score 1):

When the page loads (and after you bind the onchange function to your form elements) you should trigger any of these functions:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#select1").trigger('change');
});
```

This way it will act as if the user selected it even if the value was loaded from the database.

EDIT: czarchaic's answer is also very good, as chaining the event trigger to the event binding is more compact and it may be easier to read the code, and in this instance is probably the better solution. The answer I provided will work fine as well, and while it's longer, it as the small advantage that it will also work in cases where the function was not bound by jquery (i.e. when the event is explicitly declared in the HTML):

```
<select id=""select1" onchange="if ($(this).val() == '2' ) {
        $('#hide1').fadeIn('fast'); 
    } else {
        $('#hide1').fadeOut('fast');
    }
">
<option...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Triggering the change event after binding it.

```
    $("#select1").change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "2" ) {
            $("#hide1").fadeIn("fast"); 
        } else {
            $("#hide1").fadeOut("fast");
        }
    }).change();
```